# PHP Include does not show headers and footers

Tags: php, include

This is my first question on this site.

I am very new to programming.

I have index.html file at C:/Wamp/WWW/AddressBook/Index.html
and the header.html and footer.html files are located at C:/Wamp/WWW/AddressBook/Includes/

Now I am trying to include these files in my index.html

For Header

```
<?php include 'Includes/Header.html'; ?>
```

and for footer

```
<?php include 'Includes/Footer.html'; ?>
```

But none of both header and footer are showing up when i open index.html in my browser.

Comment: `header` or `Header`?

Comment: Try to put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` on the beginning of your code to see wether is an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can´t use PHP code in *.html files. You must use *.php instead.

Comment: This is not necessarily true. PHP may be included in .html files if the webserver is configured to expect it. See http://www.electrictoolbox.com/apache-parse-html-as-php/ for an example.

Comment: If I rename index.html to index.php then how should I run my project? Sorry for asking this, but this is my fifth day in php.

Comment: Like you were doing it: in a web browser. As the guys were saying, if your server is configured in the correct way, your browser will catch your index.php file as any normal one.

Comment: I dont know about servers but I double click on index.html and internet explorer opens a table that I have created in code but after renaming this file to index.php internet explorer opens up a dialog asking me to download index.php file

Comment: That´s because a *.php file is suppoused to be parsed (read) by the PHP interpreter, no by a normal browser. Did you downloaded PHP?

Comment: may be i am confused or you are not understanding me. after renaiming to index.php when i open index.php with internet explorer i expect to see the same table which i saw while the file was not renamed but i see the file download dialog instead of that table now.

Comment: I am sorry I got it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6):

Do your Apache understand `.html` as php file?

If not, rename your `index.html` to `index.php`.

Comment: Indeed, if it is not configured, the HTTP server (Apache) may not use the PHP interpretor to render the content. check the code source of your page (on your browser)

Comment: If I rename index.html to index.php then how should I run my project? Sorry for asking this, but this is my fifth day in php.

Answer (score 0):

Try the

```
require('url');
```

function instead, with the () around it:

```
<?php require('Includes/Header.html'); ?>
<?php require('Includes/Feader.html'); ?>
```

Also make sure that your folder is actually Includes with an uppercase I and make sure that your Header and Footer are also uppercase in reality.

I really recommend NOT using uppercases in folders and file names; it become way more messier. An exception would be for CLASSES, functions and files should (to avoid mistakes) start with a lowercase but classes should start with an upper-case.

Back to require:

The website should crash if the required file is not found, so you can make sure that you're actually requiring the particular file.

If this doesn't work then you probably have to check into your PHP configurations. If you're not using the project localhost then you should consider changing a web-service, unless you can contact the service provider or modify it on your own.